# QT: how to properly clean up QSettings to prevent memory leak?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I have written the following small exemplar test case which simply writes a single key/value into a `QSettings` object (using **Qt 5.5**):

```
#include <QSettings>

int main()
{
    QSettings settings("/tmp/settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

    std::string data = "world";
    QByteArray arr(data.c_str(), data.size());

    settings.setValue("hello", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled it as follows:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -I${QTDIR}/include -I${QTDIR}/include/QtCore -fpic \
        -L${QTDIR}/lib -Wl,-R -Wl,"$QTDIR/lib" -lQt5Core -o test
```

Running it produces no `stdout`/`stderr` output, as expected

```
$ ./test
```

However, we can see that it worked as expected by looking at the `"settings.ini"` file it created:

```
$ cat /tmp/settings.ini 
[General]
hello=@ByteArray(world)
```

However, running it though `valgrind` reports a **memory leak**:

```
$ valgrind --quiet --leak-check=full ./test

==2148== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 4
==2148==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2148==    by 0x4EC4CA1: qrand() (in ${QTDIR}/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.5.0)
==2148==    by 0x5012CC3: ??? (in ${QTDIR}/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.5.0)
==2148==    by 0x4FE6291: QFile::open(QFlags<QIODevice::OpenModeFlag>) (in ${QTDIR}/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.5.0)
==2148==    by 0x5013350: QTemporaryFile::open(QFlags<QIODevice::OpenModeFlag>) (in ${QTDIR}/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.5.0)
==2148==    by 0x505CA7D: ??? (in ${QTDIR}/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.5.0)
==2148==    by 0x505DE8C: ??? (in ${QTDIR}/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.5.0)
==2148==    by 0x4FF5A3B: QLockFile::tryLock(int) (in ${QTDIR}/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.5.0)
==2148==    by 0x503DE80: ??? (in ${QTDIR}/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.5.0)
==2148==    by 0x503F0C8: QSettings::~QSettings() (in ${QTDIR}/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.5.0)
==2148==    by 0x400E72: main (in /home/steve/test)
==2148==
```

As can be seen this is originating in the `QSettings` destructor.

**`QSettings::sync()`:**

Note that calling `settings.sync()` makes no difference to the memory leak, all it does is move the leak to originate from within `sync()`, rather than the destructor.

This is to be expected, since the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#sync) states that `sync()` is called from the destructor.

**Question:**

How can I properly clean up to prevent this memory leak?

Comment: I'm using Visual Leak detector 2.4RC2 in Qt Creator 3.5.0. It doesn't detect any memory leaks.

Comment: Does that suggest that QtCreator is suppressing Visual Leak detector reporting the memory leak then?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm on windows anyway, but also Qt 5.5. Maybe it's a qt bug in your built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Qt bug, but you don't know yet if it's important or not. Check if you can make *more* memory leak. Do this whole thing 1000 times in a loop and if it leaks 1000 `int`s, you should definitely file a bug report. Otherwise it'll have low priority.

> How can I properly clean up to prevent this memory leak?

You already are properly cleaning up. It's C++ and RAII classes, you shouldn't have to do anything. It's not C.

Comment: Done, and it still only leaks 4 bytes, so no big issue. I have resolved this by creating a suppression file, and just ignoring the issue